# iterate over elements of array column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

Need to iterate over an array of Pyspark Data frame column for further processing

```
pyspark_cols=["tags"]
list_array_elements_data=[A:XXXX,B:BBCCC,C:DDCCC]

for row in df.collect():  
  values = row["list_array_elements_data"]
  print(values)
```

Issue:

printing the data as is, only single quotes being addded to source data.
['A:XXXX','B:BBCCC','C:DDCCC']

Expected Output -Data for values to be printed, so that i can parse further each record.
In Next step I need to loop through each record eg as below.
Some how i dont find any fucntions in pyspark to loop though each element of array column.

col1 col2

A    XXXX

B    BBCCC

C    DDCCC

Comment: Just add another inner loop to print values: "for value in values: print(value)"

Comment: If i add that, it is loosing the record to which it belongs to, it just printing as raw data as below. I do have multiline data in real pyspark dataframe columns
AXXXX
BBBCCC
CDDCCC

Comment: Do you mean you want the print the values of the same row in 1 line ? You can do this: print(' '.join(values)) instead of values